# can 'vim' open a large file in read only mode as fast as 'less'?

Tags: linux, vim

I usually use 'less' to browse log files. But, sometimes, I need to use vim for its superior navigation facilities. But, the larger the log files, the longer it takes for vim to load them. 'less' seems to load them almost instantly.

Opening in read-only mode using 'vim -R' doesn't help.
Are there any other options using which I can open large files with vim quickly?
Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: The issue is most often syntax highlighting and other filetype-specific magic eating up CPU. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files and the linked plugin.

Comment: What superior navigation do you want exactly? `less` comes with a lot of Vi-like commands like `/foo`, `?bar`, `^F`, `^B`, `^D`, `^U`… it even does marks.

Comment: @honk, the link that you have provided is the same one that 'devnull' has given. Is there any other way we can suppress syntax highlighting?

Comment: @romainl I was referring to the search related navigation using *, #, [I  and %g. Even navigation on the same line when I'm explaining the log contents to a colleague viz. W, B, f, F etc.

Comment: @Will, could you please leave some reason as to why you felt it is off topic? In the closed questions' FAQ, I feel it falls into the category : "software tools commonly used by programmers". This is a problem many of my colleagues are facing and we wished to know if there was a way out. Would it be appropriate to ask it else where?

Comment: You need to open large log files quickly, right?  Finding a reader that opens large files quickly isn't programming related.  Normally, finding which program can quickly open large files is a SU subject.  But you have an answer selected below.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your response. I'd like to clarify a bit. I was not trying to find some reader that could open large files quickly. I wanted to specifically use 'vim' because of its superior navigation facilities ( and of course it's an editor I've good command on) and was trying to find out if there were any options which I could use with it to help speed up when loading large files.   Please let me know if it is still inappropriate here. Anyway, I shall be more careful in asking questions here in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting `vim` without plugins:

`vim -u NONE`

You might also want to consider other options outlined [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files).

Alternatively, consider removing portions of log files before opening up in an editor.  Try using [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/) instead of `grep`.  The `-Q` option makes ack treat the pattern as a literal and should be considerably faster (similar to `grep -F`).

`awk -Q pattern huge-file | vim -`

Prefixing the above command with `LANG=C` might help if you're using `UTF-8` locale.

Comment: `-u NONE` prevents sourcing your `~/.vimrc`. `--noplugin` is what prevents sourcing plugins.

Comment: Niether -u NONE nor --noplugin has improved the lowest load time across several attempts which is 3.5 seconds for an 871 MB log file. Moreover, I'm getting a syntax error on the ' if ! exists' line when using the vimrc specifed in devnull's link so I couldn't use that.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What's the version of vim?

Comment: @devnull, my vim version is 7.2.411. The error I am getting is E15: Invalid expression:  !exists("my_auto_commands_loaded")

Comment: Does your `~/.vimrc` contain `CR+LF` line endings?

Comment: file ~/.vimrc says : UTF-8 Unicode text. So I guess not. In fact, this is the only content in my .vimrc. Prior to this, I had an empty .vimrc

Comment: odd, nothing in the above link should transform the file into UTF-8 Unicode.  check for extraneous characters in the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32257/discussion-between-vrk001-and-devnull)