# Handle minified Javascript/CSS in Vim

Tags: vim

Elixir's Phoenix framework, but it's not the only one, dumps a minified version of (what I think is) Bootstrap's css into some of its css files. This also sometimes happens with Javascript.

When editing any of these with Vim, there basically exists this one enormously long line which vim chokes on, not showing it unless the cursor is on the line, and making all the rest of vim behave in a horrible sluggish way, where often lines after this one do not show anymore. Here is the highlighted line:

[image]

Is there a plugin or setting that can handle this annoying situation somehow?

For reference, here is the "raw" file. Notice the enormous length of line 9.

```
/* Includes some default style for the starter application.V
 * This can be safely deleted to start fresh.
 */

/* Milligram v1.3.0 https://milligram.github.io
 * Copyright (c) 2017 CJ Patoilo Licensed under the MIT license
 */

*,*:after,*:before{box-sizing:inherit}html{box-sizing:border-box;font-size:62.5%}body{color:#000000;font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size:1.6em;font-weight:300;line-height:1.6}blockquote{border-left:0.3rem solid #d1d1d1;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;padding:1rem 1.5rem}blockquote *:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.button,button,input[type='button'],input[type='reset'],input[type='submit']{background-color:#0069d9;border:0.1rem solid #0069d9;border-radius:.4rem;color:#fff;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-size:1.1rem;font-weight:700;height:3.8rem;letter-spacing:.1rem;line-height:3.8rem;padding:0 3.0rem;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap}.button:focus,.button:hover,button:focus,button:hover,input[type='button']:focus,input[type='button']:hover,input[type='reset']:focus,input[type='reset']:hover,input[type='submit']:focus,input[type='submit']:hover{background-color:#606c76;border-color:#606c76;color:#fff;outline:0}.button[disabled],button[disabled],input[type='button'][disabled],input[type='reset'][disabled],input[type='submit'][disabled]{cursor:default;opacity:.5}.button[disabled]:focus,.button[disabled]:hover,button[disabled]:focus,button[disabled]:hover,input[type='button'][disabled]:focus,input[type='button'][disabled]:hover,input[type='reset'][disabled]:focus,input[type='reset'][disabled]:hover,input[type='submit'][disabled]:focus,input[type='submit'][disabled]:hover{background-color:#0069d9;border-color:#0069d9}.button.button-outline,button.button-outline,input[type='button'].button-outline,input[type='reset'].button-outline,input[type='submit'].button-outline{background-color:transparent;color:#0069d9}.button.button-outline:focus,.button.button-outline:hover,button.button-outline:focus,button.button-outline:hover,input[type='button'].button-outline:focus,input[type='button'].button-outline:hover,input[type='reset'].button-outline:focus,input[type='reset'].button-outline:hover,input[type='submit'].button-outline:focus,input[type='submit'].button-outline:hover{background-color:transparent;border-color:#606c76;color:#606c76}.button.button-outline[disabled]:focus,.button.button-outline[disabled]:hover,button.button-outline[disabled]:focus,button.button-outline[disabled]:hover,input[type='button'].button-outline[disabled]:focus,input[type='button'].button-outline[disabled]:hover,input[type='reset'].button-outline[disabled]:focus,input[type='reset'].button-outline[disabled]:hover,input[type='submit'].button-outline[disabled]:focus,input[type='submit'].button-outline[disabled]:hover{border-color:inherit;color:#0069d9}.button.button-clear,button.button-clear,input[type='button'].button-clear,input[type='reset'].button-clear,input[type='submit'].button-clear{background-color:transparent;border-color:transparent;color:#0069d9}.button.button-clear:focus,.button.button-clear:hover,button.button-clear:focus,button.button-clear:hover,input[type='button'].button-clear:focus,input[type='button'].button-clear:hover,input[type='reset'].button-clear:focus,input[type='reset'].button-clear:hover,input[type='submit'].button-clear:focus,input[type='submit'].button-clear:hover{background-color:transparent;border-color:transparent;color:#606c76}.button.button-clear[disabled]:focus,.button.button-clear[disabled]:hover,button.button-clear[disabled]:focus,button.button-clear[disabled]:hover,input[type='button'].button-clear[disabled]:focus,input[type='button'].button-clear[disabled]:hover,input[type='reset'].button-clear[disabled]:focus,input[type='reset'].button-clear[disabled]:hover,input[type='submit'].button-clear[disabled]:focus,input[type='submit'].button-clear[disabled]:hover{color:#0069d9}code{background:#f4f5f6;border-radius:.4rem;font-size:86%;margin:0 .2rem;padding:.2rem .5rem;white-space:nowrap}pre{background:#f4f5f6;border-left:0.3rem solid #0069d9;overflow-y:hidden}pre>code{border-radius:0;display:block;padding:1rem 1.5rem;white-space:pre}hr{border:0;border-top:0.1rem solid #f4f5f6;margin:3.0rem 0}input[type='email'],input[type='number'],input[type='password'],input[type='search'],input[type='tel'],input[type='text'],input[type='url'],textarea,select{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none;background-color:transparent;border:0.1rem solid #d1d1d1;border-radius:.4rem;box-shadow:none;box-sizing:inherit;height:3.8rem;padding:.6rem 1.0rem;width:100%}input[type='email']:focus,input[type='number']:focus,input[type='password']:focus,input[type='search']:focus,input[type='tel']:focus,input[type='text']:focus,input[type='url']:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus{border-color:#0069d9;outline:0}select{background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="14" viewBox="0 0 29 14" width="29"><path fill="#d1d1d1" d="M9.37727 3.625l5.08154 6.93523L19.54036 3.625"/></svg>') center right no-repeat;padding-right:3.0rem}select:focus{background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="14" viewBox="0 0 29 14" width="29"><path fill="#0069d9" d="M9.37727 3.625l5.08154 6.93523L19.54036 3.625"/></svg>')}textarea{min-height:6.5rem}label,legend{display:block;font-size:1.6rem;font-weight:700;margin-bottom:.5rem}fieldset{border-width:0;padding:0}input[type='checkbox'],input[type='radio']{display:inline}.label-inline{display:inline-block;font-weight:normal;margin-left:.5rem}.row{display:flex;flex-direction:column;padding:0;width:100%}.row.row-no-padding{padding:0}.row.row-no-padding>.column{padding:0}.row.row-wrap{flex-wrap:wrap}.row.row-top{align-items:flex-start}.row.row-bottom{align-items:flex-end}.row.row-center{align-items:center}.row.row-stretch{align-items:stretch}.row.row-baseline{align-items:baseline}.row .column{display:block;flex:1 1 auto;margin-left:0;max-width:100%;width:100%}.row .column.column-offset-10{margin-left:10%}.row .column.column-offset-20{margin-left:20%}.row .column.column-offset-25{margin-left:25%}.row .column.column-offset-33,.row .column.column-offset-34{margin-left:33.3333%}.row .column.column-offset-50{margin-left:50%}.row .column.column-offset-66,.row .column.column-offset-67{margin-left:66.6666%}.row .column.column-offset-75{margin-left:75%}.row .column.column-offset-80{margin-left:80%}.row .column.column-offset-90{margin-left:90%}.row .column.column-10{flex:0 0 10%;max-width:10%}.row .column.column-20{flex:0 0 20%;max-width:20%}.row .column.column-25{flex:0 0 25%;max-width:25%}.row .column.column-33,.row .column.column-34{flex:0 0 33.3333%;max-width:33.3333%}.row .column.column-40{flex:0 0 40%;max-width:40%}.row .column.column-50{flex:0 0 50%;max-width:50%}.row .column.column-60{flex:0 0 60%;max-width:60%}.row .column.column-66,.row .column.column-67{flex:0 0 66.6666%;max-width:66.6666%}.row .column.column-75{flex:0 0 75%;max-width:75%}.row .column.column-80{flex:0 0 80%;max-width:80%}.row .column.column-90{flex:0 0 90%;max-width:90%}.row .column .column-top{align-self:flex-start}.row .column .column-bottom{align-self:flex-end}.row .column .column-center{-ms-grid-row-align:center;align-self:center}@media (min-width: 40rem){.row{flex-direction:row;margin-left:-1.0rem;width:calc(100% + 2.0rem)}.row .column{margin-bottom:inherit;padding:0 1.0rem}}a{color:#0069d9;text-decoration:none}a:focus,a:hover{color:#606c76}dl,ol,ul{list-style:none;margin-top:0;padding-left:0}dl dl,dl ol,dl ul,ol dl,ol ol,ol ul,ul dl,ul ol,ul ul{font-size:90%;margin:1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3.0rem}ol{list-style:decimal inside}ul{list-style:circle inside}.button,button,dd,dt,li{margin-bottom:1.0rem}fieldset,input,select,textarea{margin-bottom:1.5rem}blockquote,dl,figure,form,ol,p,pre,table,ul{margin-bottom:2.5rem}table{border-spacing:0;width:100%}td,th{border-bottom:0.1rem solid #e1e1e1;padding:1.2rem 1.5rem;text-align:left}td:first-child,th:first-child{padding-left:0}td:last-child,th:last-child{padding-right:0}b,strong{font-weight:bold}p{margin-top:0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight:300;letter-spacing:-.1rem;margin-bottom:2.0rem;margin-top:0}h1{font-size:4.6rem;line-height:1.2}h2{font-size:3.6rem;line-height:1.25}h3{font-size:2.8rem;line-height:1.3}h4{font-size:2.2rem;letter-spacing:-.08rem;line-height:1.35}h5{font-size:1.8rem;letter-spacing:-.05rem;line-height:1.5}h6{font-size:1.6rem;letter-spacing:0;line-height:1.4}img{max-width:100%}.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:' ';display:table}.float-left{float:left}.float-right{float:right}

/* General style */
h1{font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25}
h2{font-size: 2.8rem; line-height: 1.3}
h3{font-size: 2.2rem; letter-spacing: -.08rem; line-height: 1.35}
h4{font-size: 1.8rem; letter-spacing: -.05rem; line-height: 1.5}
h5{font-size: 1.6rem; letter-spacing: 0; line-height: 1.4}
h6{font-size: 1.4rem; letter-spacing: 0; line-height: 1.2}
```

#### EDIT

I have turned syntax highlighting off and this helps a bit (though is not ideal), but still the offending line does not show in Vim unless I'm actually on it, and it still feels sluggish.

Comment: [Make vim faster with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269939/7976758)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469577/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LargeFile plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) (also referenced by answers suggested in the comments) adapts many Vim options to make it faster when a huge file is loaded.

In your case, it's not so much the total file size, but the extremely large (single) line. I would call that a mutilation, even a bug, because it severely impacts editing (regardless of the editor). In my opinion, that should be changed so that there's no necessity to directly edit the resulting file, only the contributing source (with the short, readable lines), and to join them in the build process.

Your screenshot already shows the effect of [`:help 'synmaxcol'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27synmaxcol%27); the coloring stops somewhere. I'd usually recommend to reduce that further, but you've already reported problems with `:syntax off`, which is an even bigger hammer to wield.
The slowness (in syntax highlighting and otherwise) is usually caused by regular expressions that spend a long time digesting the line. These could be used by *indent* or *fold* expressions, for example.

```
:setlocal indentexpr= foldexpr=
```

might be worth a try. For further troubleshooting, setting [`'verbose'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27verbose%27) to a high value and checking what's happening is a good idea.

For a good editing experience, it would be best to convert the long line to multiple shorter ones. A [`'formatprg'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27) specific to CSS, or alternatively a quick `:substitute` should do the job, and still keep the CSS syntax intact. If you don't want to persist that change, the original line could be stored and restored prior to saving. With `:autocmd BufWrite{Pre,Post}`, this could even be fully automated, but that implementation effort will only be worth it if you have to edit these files often, and no other solution is possible.

Comment: I agree with you that the problem is with the Phoenix stack which causes this difficult situation, and not really with vi(m) or any other editor. I will reach out to the Phoenix people and in the meantime use some online "beautifying" tool to unparse the minification. If and when I have found the best such tool I will post it as an addendum to your answer.

Comment: If you haven't found those already, both [csstidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) and [css-beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/) can do that job.